# BIRT report - add a value to all

Tags: report, birt

```
╔═════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ id  ║ seconds ║ ... ║
╠═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ A   ║ 30      ║ ... ║
║ B   ║ 20      ║ ... ║
║ ... ║ ...     ║ ... ║
║ All ║ 10      ║ ... ║
╚═════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

I have data where "id" can be "All", which means that it impacts all other ids (it is NOT a "Total").

I need to do charts, and I want the chart to sum the value of id "All" to all others ids, instead of creating a bar to "All" parameter.

I want to do a chart, reading the table like this:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ id  ║ seconds ║ ... ║
╠═════╬═════════╬═════╣
║ A   ║ 40      ║ ... ║
║ B   ║ 30      ║ ... ║
║ ... ║ ...     ║ ... ║
╚═════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

Is this possible in BIRT?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in many ways.

For the choice of solutions you have to give more information.
Is there only one id 'all'?
Are the other ID's unique?

If so, I would check in the fetch script if the ID value is 'all' and if so, put the value of seconds in a global variable.

You can then use this variable to add it to all the seconds in the table.
Use the table filter or row visibility to hide the 'all' ID.

You can use tables, crosstabs or datasets as a datasource if you want to display this information as a graph.